# How to use spaces in a bash alias name?

Tags: unix, bash, alias

I am trying to create an aliases in bash.  What I want to do is map `ls -la` to `ls -la | more`

In my .bashrc file this is what I attempted:

`alias 'ls -la'='ls -la | more'`

However it does not work because (I assume) it has spaces in the alias name.  Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Why not do `alias lsm='ls -la | more'`

Answer (score 192, accepted):

The [Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) states "For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases." Here is a shell function that replaces `ls` and causes output to be piped to `more` if the argument consists of (only) `-la`.

```
ls() {
    if [[ $@ == "-la" ]]; then
        command ls -la | more
    else
        command ls "$@"
    fi
}
```

As a one-liner:

```
ls() { if [[ $@ == "-la" ]]; then command ls -la | more; else command ls "$@"; fi; }
```

Automatically pipe output:

```
ls -la
```

Comment: why do you need to use double brackets inside the if statement?

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude: The double-bracket form is more powerful and I use it by habit. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Comment: So what is the final command?  alias ls='ls()' ??

Comment: @Jeef: No, my answer uses a function *instead* of an alias. I have edited it to try to make it clearer.

Comment: What is `command` for here? Why not just `ls -la | more` or `ls "$@"`?

Comment: @merlinpatt: `command` prevents the function from being called recursively.

Comment: Very useful, I wanted to use a an alias to replace git push with a behaviour that would change when git push was called from different directories.
If you put a function in .bash_aliases it will be usable from your user folder and subfolder, just as an alias would.

Comment: @Simonlbc: Note that `.bash_aliases` is most likely a distribution or locally defined feature rather than a default Bash feature.

Comment: @Simonlbc Instead of modifying the current `git push` behavior, I would suggest creating a new [Git Alias](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases), e.g. `git my-push`.

Comment: @FranklinYu why?

Comment: @Simonlbc To make sure that tutorials online will surely work on my environment. Maybe more of a personal choice.

Comment: Take care when naming the function that you don't conflict with the `bash-completion` (command autocomplete) function. I spent a bit of time troubleshooting `tmux`, having created a function `_tmux` to which to alias the command, but discovered that the `bash-completion` for `tmux` also used `_tmux` to drive the autocomplete. So, I created the function `_TMUX` instead.

Answer (score 73):

From the [alias man page](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html):

> The first word of each simple command,
>   if unquoted, is checked to see if it
>   has an alias. If so, that word is
>   replaced by the text of the alias. The
>   alias name and the replacement text
>   may contain any valid shell input,
>   including shell metacharacters, with
>   the exception that the alias name may
>   not contain `='.

So, only the first word is checked for alias matches which makes multi-word aliases impossible.  You may be able to write a shell script which checks the arguments and calls your command if they match and otherwise just calls the normal `ls` (See [@Dennis Williamson's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/105375/bash-spaces-in-alias-name/105389#105389))

Comment: +1 For explaining why I am not allowed to use ls -la as an alias.

Comment: This was helpful because instead of trying to solve it it answered the question.  I came here because i wanted to create an alias with a space in it and that just won't happen.

Comment: This not only answered my question, but gave me valuable insight into how the aliasing mechanism actually works. Your quote from the man page was quite helpful.

Answer (score 23):

A slightly improved approach taken from Dennis' answer:

```
function ls() {
  case $* in
    -la* ) shift 1; command ls -la "$@" | more ;;
    * ) command ls "$@" ;;
  esac
}
```

Or the one-liner:

```
function ls() { case $* in -la* ) shift 1; command ls -la "$@" | more ;; * ) command ls "$@" ;; esac }
```

This allows for further options/arguments to be appended after the command if needed, for example `ls -la -h`

Comment: How does this handle if I want `ls -lat` to be excluded from this treatment? I would need to put a case to handle it above the `-la*` entry, yes?

Comment: Thanks. Useful for me with docker : `function d() {
  case $* in
    c* ) shift 1; command docker container "$@" ;;
    n* ) shift 1; command docker network "$@" ;;
    * ) command docker "$@" ;;
  esac
}` .   But unfortunately autocomplete won't work

Answer (score -1):

You can invoke this alias still, but you need quotation in order that the space is part of the command word.  So `"ls -la" -p pattern` will pass the `-p pattern` option to `more`, not `ls`.