# Is there a way to alias a multi-worded command in Unix?

Tags: unix, alias

I am trying to alias the command `sudo shutdown` but in my `.profile` I can't just do `alias "sudo shutdown"="my command"`. Is there another way to alias multi-worded commands in Unix?

Comment: I tried out all of these techniques and they all worked! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Try also the solution in my *edit*, as I realised that you really intended to have 'sudo shutdown' as an alias a little too late.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The alias name is on the left hand side, so you can have any multiworded command in the right:

```
alias my_alias="multi worded command"
```

EDIT: However, if you really want to have aliases names of multiple words -- in your example, if you really want "sudo shutdown" to be the alias, you can work around this by using the following alias feature (in the bash manual):

```
A trailing space in  value causes the next word to be checked for
alias substitution when the alias is expanded.
```

So, if you still want to use `sudo` with other commands but not with `shutdown` and if you can afford to alias `shutdown` to something else, you can have:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
alias shutdown="echo nope"
```

Now, `sudo anything_else` will work as expected (assuming you don't have an alias for `anything_else`, but if you have it wouldn't have worked before either);
but `sudo shutdown` will be equivalent to `sudo echo nope` and it'll print that string.

Comment: Thanks, underrated answer; I've been using `alias cd="cd "` with single-letter aliases `alias X="<directory-with-long-name>"` to jump from place to place more easily.

Comment: Agree, this is actually super useful. I mis-type git commands, this solves that for me: `alias gti="git "` and `alias lgo="log"`

Comment: How would I go about aliasing `pip install` to `python -m pip install` when I have already aliased `pip` to `pip3` and `python` to `python3`?

Answer (score 4):

Use a function:

```
foo() { if [ "$1" = "bar" ]; then echo "doing something..."; fi; }
```

Comment: You probably want an `else` case so that the original command runs if the second parameter _isn't_ `bar`: `foo() { if [ "$1" = "bar" ]; then echo "doing something..."; else command foo "$@"; fi; }`

Answer (score 4):

To quote from: [Bash: Spaces in alias name](https://superuser.com/questions/105375/bash-spaces-in-alias-name)

The [Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) states "For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases." Here is a shell function that replaces `ls` and causes output to be piped to `more` if the argument consists of (only) `-la`.

```
ls() {
    if [[ $@ == "-la" ]]; then
        command ls -la | more
    else
        command ls "$@"
    fi
}
```

As a one-liner:

```
ls() { if [[ $@ == "-la" ]]; then command ls -la | more; else command ls "$@"; fi; }
```

Automatically pipe output:

```
ls -la
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to just put a executable file in /usr/local/bin (be sure that is in your path) that then contains the commands I wish to run.  The name of the script would be the command that comes up. be sure to chmod +x /usr/local/bin/your_script.

So the script could be called 'shutdown'

The contents of the file shutdown would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo shutdown
```

That opens a whole new world. You could then have a couple commands or even a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "hi"
# more stuff. ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dash as a work around: `alias sudo-shutdown="your command"`