# Want to prevent accidental shutdowns, reboot, etc by aliasing commands such as shutdown

Tags: linux, bash, bashrc, bash-alias

I am trying to alias commands such as `shutdown`, `reboot`, etc. I am aware that this is not a fool proof way to block access, however this is just to prevent accidental execution.

I have looked at [superuser.com/questions/244342](https://superuser.com/questions/244342/is-there-a-way-to-alias-a-multi-worded-command-in-unix)
and all the links given within it.

To alias something like `sudo /sbin/shutdown` I would first have to alias `sudo` individually and then `/sbin/shutdown` to `echo 'Not allowed'`.

However this doesn't seem to work as `sudo` obviously executes it at root. So, aliasing these in the `.bashrc` of the user is pointless. How do I go about solving my problem? I do not want to modify any system attributes such as the `.bashrc` of root user, etc.

Comment: Uhm... how exactly do you accidentally type `sudo shutdown now`?

Comment: We're giving access to some users who might do that by mistake.

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question, but possibly a more viable approach - look at installing the `molly-guard` package.  Very useful when you frequently forget which machine your shell is running on!

Answer (score 1):

As you have correctly observed,
shell aliases are not suitable for your purpose.

The correct way to avoid accidental execution of these commands with `sudo` is to update your configuration of `sudo` (using `visudo`) and prevent access completely. You could designate a group whose members are allowed to execute these commands with `sudo`, and nobody else.

Answer (score 1):

**Ok so the '*correct*' approach is to not give these users sudo, but it seems like this is one of those situations you can't avoid giving the users this access (Lets say you did stop them running shutdown, they might just `rm -rf /*` instead)**

However, to stop them running specific commands via sudo, you can control it in the sudoers file:

Firstly we define an alias for shutting down a system in `/etc/sudoers.conf`

`Cmnd_Alias SHUTDOWN = /usr/sbin/shutdown`

And then we remove the ability for anyone in the wheel group, to run this command:

`%wheel     ALL = ALL, !SHUTDOWN`

This means that all users can run all commands on all machines, other than those in the shutdown cmnd_Alias.

`man sudoers` will explain this in far more detail, and in fact contains almost this exact explanation. Also note, this would not stop someone deliberately trying to run the shutdown command, only those who accidentally ran it without realising (maybe because they are logged into the wrong machine).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you successfully prevent the user from running all *commands* that are directly responsible for a reboot, a user with `sudo` access (where the sudo access *isn't* whitelisted to a specific set of binaries that they lack permission to modify, and which can't possibly be manipulated into running reboot code) can still reboot the system via:

1. Download the source code to a program like `reboot` or `halt` (e.g. in GNU binutils, IIRC), compile it using `gcc`, then run `sudo ./reboot` on their local copy.
2. Write a program in Ruby, Python, C/C++, Java, etc. that calls the appropriate syscalls to initiate a reboot or shutdown.
3. There are probably tricky things they can do with symlinks or hardlinks to get around a blacklist. These things are always difficult to handle from a security perspective, but I don't have any concrete examples off the top of my head.

If you're 100% sure that all the binaries you give the user the permission to run under `sudo` can't be manipulated into executing arbitrary code (which leads to items 1 or 2 above), then *maybe* it'd be OK. But a crafty user (or program running as that user) can still exploit security vulnerabilities in any of those programs to elevate and reboot/shutdown.

If you're completely confident that all users with `sudo` access will *cooperate* with you and not attempt to do things they're not allowed to do, then the blacklist should be fine to prevent "accidents". But then you should be prepared to accept the consequences *if* someone decides to deviate from policy for whatever reason.

If you have any sliver of doubt about the users, it's better to give each user a VM or a secure container.

Comment: Could they copy the shutdown bin to their home?