# Bash alias/function to precede every "git diff" with "clear"

Tags: bash, git, bash-alias

Every time I do `git diff` I'd like my bash to do `clear & git diff` instead.

I tried to tweak an answer at "[Bash: Spaces in alias name](https://superuser.com/questions/105375/bash-spaces-in-alias-name)" like this:

```
git() {
    if [[ $@ == "diff" ]]; then
        command clear && git diff
    else
        command git "$@"
    fi
}
```

But unfortunately, this does not work (the command line ends up in a sort of infinite loop switching between `bash` and `git` forever and I need `[CTRL|CMD]+C` to break from it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things like `command` or `sudo` do not magically apply to the rest of the line. (Only `#` comments and the `time` builtin have such magic.)

That is, if you use `command clear && git diff`, it is first expanded to two separate commands: `command clear` (where the "command" prefix is useless) and `git diff` (where it's needed).

The correct function would be:

```
git() {
    if [[ $1 == "diff" ]]; then
        clear && command git "$@"
    else
        command git "$@"
    fi
}
```

Alternatively:

```
git() {
    if [[ $1 == diff ]]; then
        clear
    fi
    command git "$@"
}
```

(Use `"$@"` in both cases, as you might someday need `git diff --cached` or such.)