# Overwrite bash alias for git pull to include --recurse-submodules

Tags: linux, bash, git, alias, submodule

Neither functions seem to affect anything for me? Is anyone able to get them working and show me what I'm doing wrong?

I'm trying to override `git pull` to include recursive submodules whilst keeping other git commands work

```
#https://superuser.com/a/479816
function git() {
  case $* in
    -pull* ) shift 1; command git pull --recurse-submodules "$@" ;;
    * ) command git "$@" ;;
  esac
}

function ls() {
  case $* in
    -la* ) shift 1; command ls -la "$@" | more ;;
    * ) command ls "$@" ;;
  esac
}
```

Comment: Git already has options for that topic. Check `fetch.recurseSubmodules`, `push.recurseSubmodules` and `submodule.recurse`.

Comment: @DanielB git push -recurseSubmodules?

Comment: I don’t understand your question, sorry. These options go in any of the Git config files, like `repo/.git/config`, `$HOME/.gitconfig` or `/etc/gitconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

Your script doesn't make much sense in the 1st place as it's trying to match `git -pull`, `git -pulled123` and similar statements. I would recommend to read about functionalities you're trying to use, such as `case` matching with wildcard (`*`) or what `$*` means (argument string).

Regardless, not going into that too deep because it's not the way to go. The most proper way to define git aliases is and will be to use `git config --global alias.xyz "definition"`, e.g. here:

```
git config --global alias.rpull "pull --recurse-submodules"
```

You can't overwrite the command this way, but you can use a very similar one. And overriding is generally a bad idea as you might want to use regular `pull` one day and you'll have to get rid of the script at least temporarily. There are definitely cases when you don't want to pull submodules recursively. It's also suboptimal for repos without submodules.

Comment: That looks much more like what I was looking for for git config. Thanks! I'll see if I can get it working.

For trying out more ordinary usages for learning about overwrites https://superuser.com/a/479816

Any idea why I couldn't get the ls example to work?

Comment: I explained above - the main reason is that you're matching `-pull` instead of `pull`. So nothing happens like you mentioned. The asterisk isn't handled too well either and could match some aliases starting with `pull`.

Comment: Is that in the ls example or git? It matching -pull makes sense as a mistake


```
function ls() {
  case $* in
    -la* ) shift 1; command ls -la "$@" | more ;;
    * ) command ls "$@" ;;
  esac
}
```

Comment: I don't know what's your question.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't figure out the ls -la overwrite was doing in the example. Think I've figured it out as passing the command into 'more'. Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. If the answer helped, please make sure to mark it with the tick symbol.